# How to set up and provide Memberpress plugin's free registration for first 100 first coming users to website?

Tags: wordpress, memberpress

I have a WordPress social forums project which wants to provide free registration for first 100 users to the website. I have already set up the Member-press WordPress plugin.

But I haven't found any solution or hint how to set up first 100 members free registration via Member-press plugin.

Please suggest me some ideas or clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one function for the getting how many users you have:

```
count_users()
```

Using this you can easily filter and make the query whether total users is 100 or not.